# Find indices of elements equal to zero in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

NumPy has the efficient function/method [`nonzero()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to identify the indices of non-zero elements in an `ndarray` object. What is the most efficient way to obtain the indices of the elements that *do* have a value of zero?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

[numpy.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is my favorite.

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> numpy.where(x == 0)[0]
array([1, 3, 5])
```

The method `where` returns a tuple of ndarrays, each corresponding to a different dimension of the input. Since the input is one-dimensional, the `[0]` unboxes the tuple's only element.

Comment: I am trying to remember Python. Why does `where()` return a tuple?  `numpy.where(x == 0)[1]` is out of bounds. what is the index array coupled to then?

Comment: @Zhubarb - Most uses of indeces are tuples - `np.zeros((3,))` to make a 3-long vector for instance. I suspect this is to make parsing the params easy. Otherwise something like `np.zeros(3,0,dtype='int16')` versus `np.zeros(3,3,3,dtype='int16')` would be annoying to implement.

Comment: no. `where` returns a tuple of `ndarray`s, each of them corresponding to a dimension of the input. in this case the input is an array, so the output is a `1-tuple`. If x was a matrix, it would be a `2-tuple`, and so on

Comment: As of numpy 1.16, the [documentation for `numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) specifically recommends using `numpy.nonzero` directly rather than calling `where` with only one argument.

Comment: @jirassimok how do you use nonzero to find zeros as the question asks?

Comment: @mLstudent33 Exactly the same way as you would use `where`, as seen in [Dusch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24553551). As per [`where`'s documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), `where(x)` is equivalent to `asarray(x).nonzero()`.

Comment: Oh, because an expression like `x==0` returns `[True,False,False...]` and `nonzero()` returns the indies to the `True` values.  Very non-intuitive to use `nonzero()` to find zeros! (hence the original question).

Answer (score 58):

There is [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy-argwhere),

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [0, 1, 0], [7, 0, 2]])
np.argwhere(arr == 0)
```

which returns all found indices as rows:

```
array([[1, 0],    # Indices of the first zero
       [1, 2],    # Indices of the second zero
       [2, 1]],   # Indices of the third zero
      dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 29):

You can search for any scalar condition with:

```
>>> a = np.asarray([0,1,2,3,4])
>>> a == 0 # or whatver
array([ True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Which will give back the array as an boolean mask of the condition.

Comment: You can use this to access the zero elements: `a[a==0] = epsilon`

Comment: Recently found out about this notation. IMO, one of the ugliest pieces of syntactic sugar. VERY, VERY wrong, like assignment in comparison operators in C.

Answer (score 27):

You can also use `nonzero()` by using it on a boolean mask of the condition, because `False` is also a kind of zero.

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8])

>>> x==0
array([False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

>>> numpy.nonzero(x==0)[0]
array([1, 3, 5])
```

It's doing exactly the same as `mtrw`'s way, but it is more related to the question ;)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this is the advised use of `nonzero` method to check conditions.

Answer (score 7):

If you are working with a one-dimensional array there is a syntactic sugar:

```python
>>> x = numpy.array([1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> numpy.flatnonzero(x == 0)
array([1, 3, 5])
```

Comment: This works fine as long as I have only one condition. What if I want to search for "x == numpy.array(0,2,7)"? The result should be array([1,2,3,5,9]). But how can I get this?

Comment: You could do this with:
`numpy.flatnonzero(numpy.logical_or(numpy.logical_or(x==0, x==2), x==7))`

Answer (score 7):

You can use numpy.nonzero to find zero.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,0,2,0,3,0,0,4,0,5,0,6]).reshape(4, 3)
>>> np.nonzero(x==0)  # this is what you want
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]), array([1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1]))
>>> np.nonzero(x)
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3]), array([0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2]))
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10000)
arr[8000:8900] = 0

%timeit np.where(arr == 0)[0]
%timeit np.argwhere(arr == 0)
%timeit np.nonzero(arr==0)[0]
%timeit np.flatnonzero(arr==0)
%timeit np.amin(np.extract(arr != 0, arr))
```

```
23.4 µs ± 1.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
34.5 µs ± 680 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
23.2 µs ± 447 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
27 µs ± 506 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
109 µs ± 669 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the following way:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,0,0], [0,2,0], [1,1,0]])
>>> x
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
>>> np.nonzero(x)
(array([0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]))

# if you want it in coordinates
>>> x[np.nonzero(x)]
array([1, 2, 1, 1])
>>> np.transpose(np.nonzero(x))
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,0,2,3,6])
non_zero_arr = np.extract(x>0,x)

min_index = np.amin(non_zero_arr)
min_value = np.argmin(non_zero_arr)
```