# Delete element from multi-dimensional numpy array by value

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array

```
a = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, -1]])
```

what's the fastest way to delete all elements of value `-1` to get an array of the form

```
np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0]])
```

Comment: NumPy arrays are rigid grids - if you try to make a ragged array, you get into the horrible world of object arrays, where performance tanks and nothing works right. Consider carefully whether it's really a good idea to do this, and whether you should really be using NumPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method you might consider:

```
def iterative_numpy(a):
    mask = a != 1
    out = np.array([ a[i,mask[i]] for i xrange(a.shape[0]) ])
    return out
```

Divakar's method `loop_compr_based` calculates sums along the rows of mask and a cumulative sum of that result. This method avoids such summations **but** still has to iterate through the rows of `a`. It also returns an array of arrays. This has the annoyance that `out` has to be indexed with the syntax `out[1][2]` rather than `out[1,2]`. Comparing the times with a matrix random integer matrices:

```
In [4]: a = np.random.random_integers(-1,1, size = (3,30))

In [5]: %timeit iterative_numpy(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit loop_compr_based(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.2 us per loop

In [7]: a = np.random.random_integers(-1,1, size = (30,3))

In [8]: %timeit iterative_numpy(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.5 us per loop

In [9]: %timeit loop_compr_based(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.8 us per loop

In [10]: a = np.random.random_integers(-1,1, size = (30,30))

In [11]: %timeit iterative_numpy(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.6 us per loop

In [12]: %timeit loop_compr_based(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 36 us per loop
```

When there are more columns than rows, `iterative_numpy` wins out. When there are more rows than columns, `loop_compr_based` wins but transposing `a` first will improve the performance of both methods. When the dimensions are comparably the same, `loop_compr_based` is best.

## Important Side Discussion

Outside of the implementation, it's important to note that any numpy array which has a non-uniform shape is **not** an actual array in the sense that the values do not occupy a contiguous section of memory and further, the usual array operations will not work as expected.

As an example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2],[1]])
>>> a*2
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 1]], dtype=object)
```

Notice that numpy actually informs us that this is not the usual numpy array with the note `dtype=object`.

Thus it might be best to just make a *list* of numpy arrays and use them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 :** Using NumPy splitting of array -

```
def split_based(a, val):
    mask = a!=val
    p = np.split(a[mask],mask.sum(1)[:-1].cumsum())
    out = np.array(list(map(list,p)))
    return out
```

**Approach #2 :** Using loop comprehension, but minimal work within the loop -

```
def loop_compr_based(a, val):
    mask = a!=val
    stop = mask.sum(1).cumsum()
    start = np.append(0,stop[:-1])
    am = a[mask].tolist()
    out = np.array([am[start[i]:stop[i]] for i  in range(len(start))])
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [391]: a
Out[391]: 
array([[ 0, -1,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0, -1],
       [-1, -1,  8],
       [ 3,  7,  2]])

In [392]: split_based(a, val=-1)
Out[392]: array([[0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0], [8], [3, 7, 2]], dtype=object)

In [393]: loop_compr_based(a, val=-1)
Out[393]: array([[0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0], [8], [3, 7, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [387]: a = np.random.randint(-2,10,(1000,1000))

In [388]: %timeit split_based(a, val=-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

In [389]: %timeit loop_compr_based(a, val=-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 29 ms per loop
```

Comment: For Python 3 I believe the last line in approach #1 has to be: `out = np.array(list(map(list,p)))`

Comment: @capitalistpug For me approach #2 was 5x faster than approach #1 with : `a = np.random.randint(-2,10,(1000,1000))`.

Comment: I made a mistake as I was using py3 and as you know map is an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexes = np.where(a == -1)` to get indexes of elements
[Find indices of elements equal to zero from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588628/find-indices-of-elements-equal-to-zero-from-numpy-array)

Then delete specific elements by index with `np.delete(your_array, indexes)`
[How to remove specific elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: This does not keep the correct values in a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: The desired result is not a multidimensional array.  It's a list of ragged arrays (or object array).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
print([[y for y in x if y > -1] for x in a])
[[0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0]]
```

Comment: Not a numpy solution. Efficiency will very likely be affected if you use this.

Answer (score 0):

For almost everything you might want to do with such an array, you can use a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.htm)

```
a = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, -1]])

b=np.ma.masked_equal(a,-1)

b
Out[5]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[0 -- 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False]
 [False False False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = -1)
```

If you really want the ragged array, it can be `.compressed()` by line

```
c=np.array([b[i].compressed() for i in range(b.shape[0])])

c
Out[10]: array([array([0, 0]), array([1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0])], dtype=object)
```