# Making an index array that contains the position of some value in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a Python list that contains indices of the elements equal to 1 in another integer list (or Numpy array). What I am trying is something like this (for either 1- or 2-dimensional case):

```
#--- 1D case ---
A = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]
idx = []
for i in range( len( A ) ):
    if A[ i ] == 1 : idx.append( i )

print( idx )   # [ 0, 3, 4 ]

#--- 2D case --- 
B = [ [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 1 ] ]
idx2 = [ [] for i in range( len( B ) ) ]

for i in range( len( B ) ):
    for j in range( len( B[ i ] ) ):
        if B[ i ][ j ] == 1 : idx2[ i ].append( j )

print( idx2 )   #[ [0,3,4], [1,2] ]
```

This may also be written more compactly as

```
#--- 1D case ---
idx = [ i for i in range( len(A) ) if A[ i ] == 1 ]

#--- 2D case ---
idx2 = []
for i in range( len( B ) ):
    tmp = [ k for k in range( len(B[ i ]) ) if B[ i ][ k ] == 1 ]
    idx2.append( tmp )
```

But I am wondering if there is an even more compact way (or builtin function) that can be used for the same purpose. Is there any such convenient function in pure Python, Numpy, or elsewhere...?

Comment: have a look at the updates in my responce and check one more solution for the case when  sublists have unequal length

Comment: @Luchko Thanks for the update, I will study it also closely later. The index array I'm making is for some cluster analysis, whose size is unkonwn a priori so I used a Python list. But I could also use Numpy arrays for indexing (or convert lists -> arrays) so no problem. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `numpy.where` function

check this post

[Find indices of elements equal to zero from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588628/find-indices-of-elements-equal-to-zero-from-numpy-array)

```
import numpy as np

#-----1D case------
A = np.array([0,1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2])
print(np.where(A==1))

>>> (array([1, 4, 7]),)

#-----2D case------
A = np.array([[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,1]])
print(np.where(A==1))

>>> (array([0, 1, 2, 2]), array([1, 0, 0, 3]))
```

in the examples you provided where the sublists have different length `numpy.array` is not an option as you cannot transform your `list` to `array` (sublists length should be equal). here is one more solution:

```
B = [ [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 1 ] ]
inds = [(i,j) for j,ls in enumerate(B) for i,e in enumerate(ls) if e==1]
print(inds)

>>>> [(0, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
```

where `ls` corresponds to sublist and `e` to the element of the sublist

Comment: Thanks, it works :) (I initially had trouble with 2D case, but I needed to convert the input B array first to a numpy array...)

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.where`

```
arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

>>array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

np.where(arr == 1)

>>(array([0]), array([1]))

arr[0][1]

>>1
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is it possibly a common way to extract indices from the obtained index array like "for (i,j) in zip(id[0],id[1]): ..." ? (where id = np.where(arr == 1))

Comment: you can also write ``zip(*id)``

Comment: I see... this makes the code very simple. thanks again :)