# How to get index of all maximum values in an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In the following array there are two maximum values 5 and 5. np.argmax command returns the index of first maximum value. But I want to get the index of all maximum values in array using np.argmax. How I can do that?

```
`a= np.array([1,2,5,5,0,3])
b= np.argmax(a)
print(b)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588628/find-indices-of-elements-equal-to-zero-in-a-numpy-array):

```
a = np.array([1,2,5,5,0,3])
x = np.max(a)
b = np.where(a == x)[0]
print(b)
```

Comment: After applying condition a==x what is the purpose of [0]? Documentation says if condition is true generate x otherwise y

Comment: This is another use: "If only condition is given, return the tuple condition.nonzero(), the indices where condition is True". You need the first element of the tuple.

Comment: sorry i didn't get your point. Can you please explain what [0] stands for? Is it stand for row?

Comment: `b = np.where(a == x)` yields `(array([2, 3]),)`. Therefore, `b[0]` is `array([2, 3])` that you need.