# Find indices of zero array into an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have a numpy array

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]])
```

and I would like to get all index when array contains only zero values :

```
index 2 -> [0,0,0,0]
index 4 -> [0,0,0,0]
```

Discussion with the similar problem exists : [Find indices of elements equal to zero in a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588628/find-indices-of-elements-equal-to-zero-in-a-numpy-array)

but in this solution we get values equal to zero, instead of get array with zero as I want.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) with [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to get indices of rows where all elements == 0:

```
In [11] np.argwhere((my_array == 0).all(axis=1))
Out[11]: 
array([[2],
       [4]], dtype=int64)
```

Or [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) instead of [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) gives slightly nicer output:

```
In [12] np.nonzero((my_array == 0).all(axis=1))
Out[12]: (array([2, 4], dtype=int64),)
```