# Find indices of elements equal to zero in a PyTorch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

My question is nearly identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588628/find-indices-of-elements-equal-to-zero-in-a-numpy-array) one, with the notable difference of being in PyTorch. I would prefer not to use the Numpy solution as this would involve moving data back to the CPU. I see that, as with Numpy, PyTorch has a [nonzero](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=zero#torch.nonzero) function, however its where function (the solution in the Numpy thread I linked) has behavior different from Numpy's. 
The behavior I want is an `is_zero()` function as follows:

```
>>> arr.nonzero()
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 0]])  
>>> arr.is_zero()
tensor([[0, 0],
        [1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a boolean mask and then call `nonzero()`:

```
(arr == 0).nonzero()
```

For instance:

```
arr = torch.randint(high=2, size=(3, 3))
```

```py
tensor([[1, 1, 0],  # (0, 2)
        [1, 1, 0],  # (1, 2)
        [1, 0, 0]]) # (2, 1) and (2, 2)
```

```
(arr == 0).nonzero()
```

```
tensor([[0, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.