# Pytorch, get the index of the first 0 in as mask?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch

I have a tensor that looks like: `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)`.
I want to get the index where the first zero appears.
What would the be best way do this?

Comment: You can adapt this answer to your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/60817512/8440629

Comment: if it's guaranteed to be contiguous 1's followed by contiguous 0's then the sum will give you the index of the first 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best usage of `argmin` but it should work here I think:

```
>>> torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]).argmin()
tensor(8)
```

Comment: Oh, I'm very silly, the mask is actually a boolean mask. I'll see if `argmin` still works.

Comment: it works only if the element is minimum.

Comment: This: `mask = mask.to(torch.int16)`, solved the issue

Comment: solution from @bpfrd is more universal because it will work with any target value (not only zero)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
your_target_value = 0
your_tensor = torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])

(your_tensor == your_target_value).nonzero()[0] #first element
```

Output:

```
tensor([8])
```