# Replace zeros of an array using a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, matrix

I have created a list called **ingreso_datos**, within which I enter information, note that when working with for loops in my variables I display the result of the last list, that is, of element 15. Explanation image here:[image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AieO48E0rWr2lBRiPqN-12AYoca5), here I leave the excel: [ejercicio_ec](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2lBPuwanPtJXn1oF9)

I have created a 36x36 array of zeros, plus I have created another list called **counters**, which tells me the rows and columns to which I should replace the zeros of my previously created array.

The values that I am going to replace in the zeros matrix are given by another matrix, this 6x6 matrix, called **la_matriz**.

My problem is that when I do this with a for loop, I get *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intertuples'*.

This week I am learning the manipulation of matrices in Python so I really appreciate the feedback to these questions, regards.

And excuse my English, it is not my native language.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base = pd.ExcelFile('ejercicio_ec.xlsx')

ingreso_datos = [[ 1,    'W',    28,    29,    30,    19,    20,     21,      0,      0,      0,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 2,    'W',    31,    32,    33,    22,    23,      24,    4.5,      0,    4.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 3,    'W',    34,    35,    36,    25,    26,      27,    9.5,      0,    9.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 4,    'W',    19,    20,    21,    10,    11,      12,      0,    2.5,      0,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 5,    'W',    22,    23,    24,    13,    14,     15,    4.5,    2.5,    4.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 6,    'W',    25,    26,    27,     6,    17,      18,    9.5,    2.5,    9.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 7,    'W',    10,    11,    12,     1,     2,       3,      0,      5,      0,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 8,    'W',    13,    14,    15,     4,     5,       6,    4.5,      5,    4.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [ 9,    'W',    16,    17,    18,     7,     8,       9,    9.5,      5,    9.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [10,    'X',      19,    20,    21,    22,    23,       24,      0,    2.5,    4.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [11,    'X',      22,    23,    24,    25,    26,       27,    4.5,    2.5,    9.5,    2.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [12,    'X',      10,    11,    12,    13,    14,       15,      0,      5,    4.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [13,    'X',      13,    14,    15,    16,    17,       18,    4.5,      5,    9.5,      5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [14,    'X',       1,     2,     3,     4,     5,        6,      0,    7.5,    4.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10],
                 [15,    'X',       4,     5,     6,     7,     8,        9,    4.5,    7.5,    9.5,    7.5,    'xh24',    10]]


propies = []

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):
    if ingreso_datos[i][12] == 'xh24':
        Data = base.parse('xh24')

    for j in range(len(Data)):
        if ingreso_datos[i][13] == Data.values[j][0]:
            propies.append([Data.values[j][1], Data.values[j][2], Data.values[j][3]]) 

counters = []

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):

    b = propies [i][0]            
    c = propies [i][1]            
    d = propies [i][2]           
    e = np.sqrt((ingreso_datos[i][10]-ingreso_datos[i][8])**2+(ingreso_datos[i][11]-ingreso_datos[i][9])**2)    

    La_matriz = np.array([[ b*c/e,            0,           0,    -b*c/e,           0,            0],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**3,    c*d/e**2,         0,    c*d/e**3,     c*d/e**2],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**2,       c*d/e,         0,     c*d/e**2,      c*d/e],
                       [-b*c/e,            0,           0,     b*c/e,           0,           0],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**3,    c*d/e**2,         0,     c*d/e**3,    c*d/e**2],
                       [     0,     c*d/e**2,       c*d/e,         0,      c*d/e**2,    c*d/e]])


    # Matrix de zeros
    ceros_grande = np.zeros((36,36)) 

    counters.append([ingreso_datos[i][2], ingreso_datos[i][3], ingreso_datos[i][4],
                     ingreso_datos[i][5], ingreso_datos[i][6], ingreso_datos[i][7]])


    for _, i1, i2, i3, j1, j2, j3 in counters():

        ceros_grande[:, [i1,i2,i3,j1,j2,j3]] = La_matriz
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it when people ask something and then others respond with 'why don't you try this or that', but why don't you try `np.where()`?

It can return you the indices of the matrix that have a specific value.

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> numpy.where(x == 0)[0]
array([1, 3, 5]
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588628/find-indices-of-elements-equal-to-zero-in-a-numpy-array) for reference. It might be more efficient and less painful.